# How to pass collection to binding converter parameter in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, collections, converters

In silverlight application in c# code I'm taking data from WCF RIA services.
Then I want to pass this data (List) to chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) axis converter parameter.

```
this.specialDayClient = new SpecialDayClient();
            this.specialDayClient.SpecialDayLoaded += new EventHandler(specialDayClient_SpecialDaysLoaded);
            this.specialDayClient.SpecialDayLoadFailed += new EventHandler(specialDayClient_SpecialDaysLoadFailed);

        private void specialDayClient_SpecialDaysLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            specialDays = sender as IEnumerable<SpecialDay>;
            var binding = new Binding("ConverterBinding")
            {
                Converter = new DateToColorConverter(),
                ConverterParameter = specialDays
            };

        var setter = new Setter(ForegroundProperty, binding);


            ((DateTimeAxis)chartCashRemainders.Axes[0]).AxisLabelStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
            //After this row I get error message "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
        }

        private void specialDayClient_SpecialDaysLoadFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            specialDays = new List<SpecialDay>();
        }
```

After **((DateTimeAxis)chartCashRemainders.Axes[0]).AxisLabelStyle.Setters.Add(setter);** I'm getting error message "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the simplest way - create a new class with object collection:

```
public class SpecialDays : List<SpecialDay>
{
    public SpecialDays()
    {
        if(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
            return;

        DeviceManagementDomainContext domainContext = new DeviceManagementDomainContext();

        var query = domainContext.GetSpecialDaysForEditorQuery();
        LoadOperation<SpecialDay> operation = domainContext.Load(query);
        operation.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (operation.HasError)
            {
                if (operation.Error != null)
                {
                    operation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                }
                this.AddRange(new List<SpecialDay>());
            }
            else
            {
                List<SpecialDay> specialDays = operation.Entities.ToList();
                this.AddRange(specialDays);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then add this class in xaml code (to ):

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
        <bs2Models:SpecialDays x:Key="SpecialDays"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And add as static resource to converter:

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalAxisLabelStyle" TargetType="toolkit:DateTimeAxisLabel">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource SpecialDays}}"/>
</Style>
```